# Conditional IE Comments not working in Joomla

Tags: css, internet-explorer, joomla

We have a website, http://www.globalforcestn.com/. Everything is fine except the conditional IE comments that I put in the template. Because of this, the site is not rendered correctly in IE (specifically the menu). It is moved to the left. This is our code:

```
 <!--[if lt IE 11]>
<link href="/modules/mod_maximenuck/themes/css3megamenu/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But it won't honor the IE conditions. It will render it when the browser is set to Compatibility Mode. However, the website looks even more terrible on Compatibility Mode.

Hoping for your response. thanks!

Comment: FYI you may want to post similar questions in the future in joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer 10 standards and it means that conditiona comments for IE10 and later are considered just like regular comment (ignored by the browser)

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I just found out about that too. Thanks for the info. So do you know any CSS hacks for IE 11? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

IE stopped supporting conditional comments from IE10 onwards. Therefore conditional comments will work only on IE9, IE8, IE7 and if you still support it, IE6 (IE5 and below as well but who supports IE5?).

So, if you're targetting IE9 and below a simple `[if IE]` will do because it will be ignored by IE10 and above. If you want the above to work in IE10 you're out of luck.

See the announcement from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

your only way to target IE10+ is by using browser detection code. You can use a php functions to get the browser details like `$browser = get_browser();` and then use the `strpos` to search the browser agent string. But since your question mentions joomla. There's a php function implemented in joomla and it's easy to use. I'll share it if someone wants to try that.

```
jimport('joomla.environment.browser');     
    $browser = &JBrowser::getInstance();
    $browserType = $browser->getBrowser();
    $browserVersion = $browser->getMajor();
    $client = new JApplicationWebClient();
```

Then you can use an if else statement and compare. You can use this [link](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/) to check for IE browser user agent.

For example for IE 10 &11 I would use the following

```
        if(($browserType == 'mozilla') && ($client->engine == JApplicationWebClient::TRIDENT))  //IE11

        if(($browserType == 'msie') && ($client->engine == JApplicationWebClient::TRIDENT)) //IE10
```

Many browsers will be using mozilla but very few will be using trident and non of the popular ones do except IE. Note: that you need to check browserType as for IE 10 i think it's msie. However you need to get the revision to target specific IE, which in this case can be rv:11.0 and you can check that on a test page just use `print_r($agentString)`

In order to do that you need to use `$agentString = $browser->getAgentString();`

and then perform a string search using `strpos`
Therefore for IE 10 & 11:
     $ieagentversion10 = strpos($agentString,'10');
    $ieagentversion11 = strpos($agentString,'11');
Then you can simply add this to the If statement:

```
&& ($ieagentversion10 == true)
&& ($ieagentversion11 == true)
```